# Multiple bootable OS in primary partition

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, usb, partitioning

I have a primary partition in kali linux. Now, I want to install Windows 10 also. I have a primary partition
[image]

Kali Linux is still in the partition. I have a bootable USB. Now, I want to install Windows 10 via that bootable USB. If I install Windows 10 without formatting the disk.

Will both OS work in this computer?

Or, I can only access single one. Another will be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to install Windows first, and linux afterwards.
If not, windows might overwrite the linux boot partition - and you'll only be able to boot from Windows.

Otherwise, there are no limitations when installing linux + windows on one disk - as long as they're in separate partitions.

Comment: Sorry! I have `Kali Linux` installed. According to you, I have to install Windows then, Linux.

Comment: Yes - safest thing to do is to first create 2 partitions, then install windows, and install linux last. If you install windows after linux, you have to repair linux boot loader (grub) manually.

Comment: If you don't want to remove Kali Linux, you can install Windows to a different partition, then install Clover EFI (https://github.com/CloverHackyColor/CloverBootloader) to your EFI folder.